# Issues with fitting Articulate Storyline Player into Android' Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, articulate-storyline

I have problems with fitting and centering the articulate storyline player into my androids webview. I have tried all settings from styline player about browser size and player size, but I did not work for me. The player in portrait orientation is too big, only left part is visible. In horizontal orientation it fits the screen height, but it is not centered horizontally.

Here is my layout file:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="pcss.mywebview.MainActivity" >
</WebView>
```

And my webview settings:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

I have also tried changing settings for mWebView about zooming and others, but it did'nt work.

In chrome browser player is fitting, scaling and centering properly. I believe it can be done in my custom webView too, but I just can't find the proper settings configuration. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some more research, and it appears that this problems depends on Android version. I was testing it on Android 4.3, but on newer versions of Android this WebView problem is gone.

> Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is
>   based on Chromium. This change upgrades WebView performance and
>   standards support for HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript to match the latest
>   web browsers. Any apps using WebView will inherit these upgrades when
>   running on Android 4.4 and higher.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html